# Iterate Map using forEach and keep track of index

Tags: java, java-8, iteration, java-stream, enum-map

Let's say we have a EnumMap in java and through the iteration using streams we need to use the key of the map, the value and the index. I have implemented as in the following example:

```
EnumMap<TestEnum, List<String>> enumMap = new EnumMap<TestEnum, List<String>>(TestEnum.class);
enumMap.put(TestEnum.ONE, Arrays.asList("one", "1"));
enumMap.put(TestEnum.TWO, Arrays.asList("two", "2"));

final int[] position= {0};
enumMap.entrySet().forEach( e -> {
    List<String> objects= enumMap.get(e.getKey());
    System.out.println("Position: " position[0] + 1);
    position[0]++;
});
```

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding something, but the question at the link is about iteration over a collection (list even), which would have a different solution from iterating over a map with index (I failed to find a neat duplicate).

Comment: I have already read this link. In my example, I would prefer to use the IntStream.range to iterate over the map(doing this I will have the index). But in this case I can't find an elegant way to get the key.